# Using JSON.Net CustomCreationConverter

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net, deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize JSON in this format:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "installed": 1,
         "user_likes": 1,
         "user_education_history": 1,
         "friends_education_history": 1,
         "bookmarked": 1
      }
   ]
}
```

to a simple dictionary like this:

```
{
    "installed": true,
    "user_likes": true,
    "user_education_history": true,
    "friends_education_history": true,
    "bookmarked": true
}
```

using the `CustomCreationConverter` in `JSON.NET 4.0`.

I'm getting errors saying I can only deserialize to arrays. Is this correct? How can I "force" it to create a dictionary? Do I need to create a custom class?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Try it:

```
var convert = function(obj){
    var newObj = {};
    for(var prop in obj.data[0])
        newObj[prop] = obj.data[0][prop];
    return newObj;
}
convert({
    "data": [
        {
            "installed": 1,
            "user_likes": 1,
            "user_education_history": 1,
            "friends_education_history": 1,
            "bookmarked": 1
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: This is JavaScript - I thought the question was how to define a CustomCreationConverter in .NET to create a C# dictionary. Is there actually a way to embed JavaScript within Json.NET?

Comment: Hmm, I don't know. Sorry, I'm not a .NET programmer